# Need logic in building a UNIX Script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am asked to write a script code in UNIX for taking values from a table present in HTML page
and showing it in the console, but just to take the values of 1st column of the table.

or take the entire code in a variable and write a script such that it takes first column out of it.

Here's a sample :

```html
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">

<tr align="center">

<th>Environment</th><th>Release Track</th><th>Artifact</th><th>Name</th><th>Build #</th><th>Cert Idn</th><th>Build Idn</th><th>Request Status</th><th>Update Time</th><th>Log Info.</th><th>Initiator</th>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>DEV03</td><td>2.1.0</td><td>abpa</td><td>ecom-abpa-ear</td><td>204</td><td>82113</td><td>171242</td><td>Deployed</td><td>3/18/2013 3:10:58 PM</td><td width="70">Log info</a></td><td>CESAR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>DEV03</td><td>2.1.0</td><td>abpa</td><td>abpa_dynamic_config_properties</td><td>20</td><td>82113</td><td>167598</td><td>Deployed</td><td>3/18/2013 2:32:27 PM</td><td width="70">Log info</a></td><td>CESAR</td>

</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is at very primary level, so the answer would also be as primary level as:

cat abc.html | awk -F" " '{print $1}'

Comment: The Response I get is :
awk: no program given

Answer (score 0):

try this oneliner, it will print first column from HTML table:

```
grep -E "\<th\>|\<td\>" abc.html | awk -F "<th>|<td>" '{print $2}' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g'
```

in file abc.html is your html code. output is here:

```
system:/depot/scripts/sh # grep -Ew "\<th\>|\<td\>" abc.html | awk -F "<th>|<td>" '{print $2}' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g'
Environment
DEV03
DEV03
system:/depot/scripts/sh #
```